# How to get the names of all colors supported by Chalk?

Tags: typescript, types, type-assertion, chalk

I'm using the [Chalk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk) NPM package in TypeScript. If I dynamically set the color for Chalk, then I get a TS error. I could use a type assertion like `chalk[color] as Chalk` but I would prefer to use a type predicate if possible, which would require for me to be able to access the list of supported colors.

So, is there a way to access the list of supported colors in Chalk, or another way to resolve this issue, without using type assertions, and possibly using type predicates?

The `strict` option in `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.json` may need to be enabled, to get the error to appear.

The code is below, and the error is in the comments:

```js
import chalk from 'chalk';

function getColor(): string {
  return 'blue';
}

const color = getColor();

/**
 * Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string'
 * can't be used to index type 'Chalk & { supportsColor: ColorSupport; }'.
 *
 * No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Chalk
 * & { supportsColor: ColorSupport; }'.ts(7053)
 */
console.log(chalk[color]('test'));
```

Comment: Did you install types for 'chalk'? `npm install --save-dev @types/chalk`

Comment: The module already comes with its own types.

Comment: This code isn't throwing any errors for me.

Comment: You might need to have `strict` enabled in `tsconfig.json`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, and you do not even need a type predicate.

Chalk exports two union types that define supported foreground and background types: `ForegroundColor` and `BackgroundColor` respectively (as well as a convenience union type `Color`). You can simply import them and add one of them (or both) as the return type of your `getColor` function:

```js
import chalk, { type ForegroundColor, type BackgroundColor } from 'chalk';

function getColor(): ForegroundColor | BackgroundColor {
  return 'blue';
}

const color = getColor();

console.log(chalk[color]('test')); // OK
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/N9Ee9N)